# How do I create association by joining non primary key column

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
class Contact {
String name
String number
}

class Message {
String text
String number   
Contact contactInfo //If any
}
```

I need to join on Message.number = Contact.number. Any thoughts on creating association in Grails/GORM with non primary key column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible in GORM, and I don't know if it's even possible in regular Hibernate. But you can fake it:

```
class Message {
   String text
   String number

   static transients = ['contactInfo']

   Contact getContactInfo() {
      Contact.findByNumber(number)
   }
   void setContactInfo(Contact contact) {
      number = contact.number
   }
}
```

Comment: Sad... This is easily possible in EF. Not sure why this is not possible. Will I be able to order results based on Contact name. i.e, pagination and sorting features?

Comment: That's unfortunately the only answer I still find for this problem 2 years later - http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7964 is still not marked resolved :(

Answer (score 4):

Burt, this is possible with hibernate using the property-ref attribute